# Face that launched a thousand ships

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrases

Last Wednesday, I went out to tea with several friends, and one of the men said that he had a new girlfriend. I asked him what she looked like, and all he said was,"She has a face that launched  a thousand ships."

What does this phrase mean? And what is its origin?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a reference to [Helen of Troy](http://ancienthistory.about.com/od/troyilium/f/FaceLaunched.htm). She was said to be so beautiful that, when she was abducted, a fleet of a thousand ships set sail to win her back from Paris, sparking the Trojan Wars.

Comment: Indeed.  The missing part is that Helen of Troy was renowned for her beauty, so the friend is saying that his girlfriend is preposterously attractive.

Comment: @Matthew Correct, I'll edit it a bit

Comment: The original quote: "Was this the face that launch'd a thousand ships,
And burnt the topless towers of Ilium--
Sweet Helen, make me immortal with a kiss.--"

Answer (score 18):

If his girlfriend is even <sup>1</sup>/<sub>1000</sub>th the beauty of Helen of Troy, you can use the unit of facial beauty called the [millihelen](http://www.wordnik.com/words/millihelen):

> ```
>   –noun
> ```
>
> 1. (informal) A unit of measure of pulchritude, corresponding to the
>   amount of beauty required to launch
>   one ship.

Comment: Hahahaha!! Thank-you so much.!! I'm so going to use that tip.

Comment: Related [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17075/are-additional-intriguing-measurements-just-a-stones-throw-away/17643#17643).

Comment: I once asked my brother what a *milihelen* was, and he worked it out. Smart boy.